# React onSubmit placement

Tags: reactjs, forms, onsubmit

I have looked at multiple sources for using onSubmit functions in React and they always place onSubmit triggers as a Form attribute, like this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { register } from "../../../actions/auth/auth.action";

import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import {
    Button,
    Form,
    Label,
    Input,
  } from "reactstrap";

class Register extends Component {
    state = {
        fname: "",
        lname: "",
        email: "",
        password: ""
    };

    static propTypes = {
        register: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    };

    handleChange = e => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
    };

    handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const { fname, lname, email, password } = this.state;

        const newUser = {
            name: {
                first: fname,
                last: lname
            },
            email: {
                address: email
            },
            password
        };

        // Attempt to register user
        this.props.register(newUser);
    };

    render() {
        return(
                        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                                <Label for="fname">First Name</Label>
                                <Input
                                    type="text"
                                    name="fname"
                                    id="fname"
                                    placeholder="Enter first name"
                                    className="mb-3"
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                />

                                <Label for="lname">Last Name</Label>
                                <Input
                                    type="text"
                                    name="lname"
                                    id="lname"
                                    placeholder="Enter last name"
                                    className="mb-3"
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                />

                                <Label for="email">Email</Label>
                                <Input
                                    type="email"
                                    name="email"
                                    id="email"
                                    placeholder="Enter email"
                                    className="mb-3"
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                />

                                <Label for="password">Password</Label>
                                <Input
                                    type="password"
                                    name="password"
                                    id="password"
                                    placeholder="Enter password"
                                    className= "mb-3"
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                />
                                <Button color="primary" style={{ marginTop: "2rem" }} block>
                                    Register
                                </Button>
                        </Form>
        );
    };
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    error: state.error   
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { register }
)
(Register);
```

However, when I try this there is no way to call the function. (Ie. how does the button "know" when to call the onSubmit function when the call is a Form attrbute) I even tried added a type="submit" attribute to the button but that doesn't work either.

Comment: That looks like a custom `Button` component. What library are you using?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity - I added the imported libraries

Comment: Hmm, looks like the reactstrap `Form` component doesn't have an onSubmit prop. Have you tried using `onClick` for the `Register` button?

Comment: Yes, that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Full code would be helpful to find out the problem

Comment: I have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare type="submit" in your button `<button type="submit">send stuff</button>` The type attribute is what onSubmit form is waiting for :) and remove `e.preventDefault` from your `handleSubmit` method and try again

Comment: Although intuitive, adding the submit type to the button didn't seem to work.

Comment: @R.Antao, onSubmit should be inside Form tag... `<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>`

Comment: ...and the button with type submit :)

Comment: That is what I initially had.. I thought that would have been the solution but it didn't work

Comment: When I have the onSubmit in the Form tag, nothing at all happens  (even when setting the Button type="submit"), and when I have the onSubmit in the Button tag, the form clears as if the data submitted but I don't get a log in the console.

Comment: @R.Antao, remove `e.preventDefault` from your `handleSubmit` method and try again

Comment: You are welcome :), thank you for upvote my comments, it helps a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

The function will be called when submit event occurred.

Below code shows actions that trigger submit event.

```js
class FormComponent extends React.Component {

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('submitted');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input type="submit" /><br />
        <button>Button with no attribute</button><br />
        <button type="submit">submit typed Button</button><br />
        <button type="button">button typed Button (no submit)</button><br />
        <input type="text" value="Press enter to submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <FormComponent />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: I see your code worked, as I would expect it to. Maybe it's the fact that I'm using the reactstrap library Form components, so the props are not being passed properly?